# How do I specify the lat and long values from my current location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api place search to get details of nearby places. In this example by google, we have to specify the center: lat,lng in the function initMap(). How do I provide them from my current location?

jsfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/mayureshbakshi/xj3n2ecc/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
          zoom: 15
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
          placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I was editing the question when you commented.

Comment: OK, I couldn't possibly know that you'd post a question and then add code 10 minutes later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
   function myMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Your current location                        ');
                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos });
                marker.setMap(map);
                var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 15 };
            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

    }
```

Comment: This code gives me the co ordinates of my location. But, how do I center the map on them so that the place details that I get are around my location?

Comment: You mean you want to zoom the map?

Comment: In the initMap(), center:{lat: LAT, lng:LNG}, I want LAT and LNG values from geolocation.

Comment: this code can help you 
if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
}

Comment: you can use this for getting lat and lng

Answer (score 0):

```
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
  // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
  // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
  // locate you.


  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

For just centering the google map if you have the lat lng, you could do the following at later point.

```
map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng});
```